# How to write a proper subject line for a follow up email

Tags: etiquette, postdocs, email

I emailed a professor about a postdoc position three weeks ago. He replied me on Friday that week and showed his interest. I answered his question about partial funding in the new email but have not heard from him since then. It's been two weeks and I think it's time to send a followup email. I'm not sure how to write the subject line. Should I forward the previous email and write subject like this: Follow-up about postdoc position?
Thanks a lot. I'm a little nervous about the position and hope I can get it.

Comment: You're overthinking it. It's not a literary contest. Any subject is fine as long as it tells the reader at a glance of what the topic is. (If you really want to get into small details: sometimes it's helpful to just 'reply' to your own previous email and not change the subject for people who view their email grouped by threads, so that if they missed a previous message it will be pulled up along with the new one.)

Comment: @nengel That could be an answer ;-)

Answer (score -2):

You can reply to the email again and change the email body to "Gentle Reminder " with a smiley and you can insert [Reminder] before your previous subject

Comment: I would hesitate against adding 'smiley' in any professional or semi-professional communication.

Comment: I wouldn't change the body. If anything add the "reminder" to the subject line.